# How to filter incoming sms message number

Tags: java, android, sms, smsmanager

I made an app , which automatically responds to calls and text messages. my problem is that i dont want to send the auto reply if the incoming number is from the mobile network provider. I only want to send the auto reply if the message is from a normal number.
I was thinking of doing this (psuedo code below)

```
if (incomingNumber != +3538{
      sendMessage();
      }
```

the +353 is the country code of Ireland and all normal mobile numbers start with 08 but when the country code (+353) is used the 0 before the 8 is dropped.
If i was to do it this way I would have to add every country code in the world then. I was just thinking was their a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was:

```
if (phoneNumber.contains("+")){
    //Code Here
    }
```

I think that all normal numbers start with "+" (i.e +3538.......) 
and only service numbers don't start with this i.e(50135)